# Outlook 2010 Crashing

Tags: microsoft-outlook, microsoft-outlook-2010

Outlook 2010 crashed about 7 times so far.

Here is the printout from the eventlog

```
Faulting application name: OUTLOOK.EXE, version: 14.0.4760.1000, time stamp: 0x4ba8fefd
Faulting module name: wwlib.dll, version: 14.0.5123.5000, time stamp: 0x4c646c1f
Exception code: 0xc0000005
Fault offset: 0x00009b99
Faulting process id: 0x109c
Faulting application start time: 0x01cc21d07f475498
Faulting application path: C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Office\Office14\OUTLOOK.EXE
Faulting module path: C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Office\Office14\wwlib.dll
```

The most significant items are:
0x00009b99
and 
wwlib.dll

Nothing suspicious in the Add-ins.

Any ideas?

Comment: Is the system fully patched?  Can you try a re-install of Office?

Comment: Windows 7, Vista, or XP?  64bit obviously, but what other Office programs are installed?  Any of those crashing as well?

Comment: It's 64-bit Windows 7, SP1 applied and all other updates.  I'll keep an eye out for problems with Word 2010.  Thanks for the idea of reinstall Office 2010.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hold the CTRL key down and start Outlook. See if it will start in safe mode. Run it this way and see if it still crashes. If it does not crash, it is probably a bad add-in, and you will have to figure out which one.

If it still crashes in safe mode, your install is probably bad. Repair it in "add/remove programs" (XP) or in "Programs and Features" (windows 7).

If that does not work, you can try to rebuild your profile.

If none of that works, you may have to wipe Office and reinstall it. Use the automatic Fix-it for you version here: http://support.microsoft.com/kb/290301

Comment: Good ideas - I have deleted lots of email and the problem has gone away for now

Comment: Thtat is actually unusual that that helped. Obviously, you had to do something first to get it started. You should go back and run this: C:\Program Files\Microsoft Office\Office14\scanpst.exe. Run it multiple times until it reports no errors. This repairs structure and other errors in your data file. To find your PST file, go to Control Panel>Mail>Data files and check the location.

Answer (score 2):

I would start with running Outlook in safe mode to see whether the problem goes away.  Other possible approaches:

- create a new mail profile
- delete or rename the outlook.ost to force recreation

Comment: Good points (above answer was first, and similar that's why I ticked it)

Answer (score 1):

My situation was that customer could not send emails without Outlook immediately crashing.  Event log reported this same error pointing to OUTLOOK.EXE & wwlib.dll.

```
We ran outlook in safe mode.
scanned the .pst with scanPST tool.
turned off ALL of the Outlook add-ins, and removed a couple of them completely.
turned off all of the MS Word add-ins.
backed out the recent MS updates.
Uninstalled some unsupported apps that had been installed.
Uninstalled our antivirus software, AVG
Did a repair of Office
Removed Word and Outlook and then reinstalled them
created new profile in Outlook.
Followed advise from Technet,  MSDN, and SpiceWorks forums.
cleared out temp files in App Data under his user profile directory. 
Ran CCleaner and cleared out more temps.
upgraded to Office 2013
```

The fix?  The source of the problem was his signature file.  Something was corrupted.  Just on a whim, when i sent a test email that failed, I cleared out all of the signature from the bottom of the body of the message.  The email sent!  So we recreated the signature by copying the signature from an old sent email. SUCCESS!